# PHP: Count different numbers in string

Tags: php

I got a String like this:

> ,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11

How can I count how many different numbers are there?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.
Does the string really start with a comma. What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes it starts with a comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//remove the starting from the given string,
$input = substr($input, strpos(',', $input) + 1);

//split the string on ',' and put it in an array
$numbers = explode(',', $input);

//an array to put our unique numbers in
$counter = array();
//for each number
foreach($numbers as $number) {
  //check if it is not in the unique 'counter' array
  if(!in_array($number, $counter)) {
    //remember this unique number
    $counter[] = $number;
  }
}

//count the unique number array
$different = count($counter);
//give some output
echo "There are " . $different . " unique numbers in the given string";
```

the input variable should be your text, because your text starts with a ',' we strip it out of our input string

Comment: Thank you. That worked. btw: Not "substring". It is "substr". But with that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode function for making the `string` an array then use `array_unique` function on it for getting the unique number's of it. From this array array you can easily count how many of your number unique.

```
$str = ",10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11";

$arr = explode(",", trim($str, ","));

$arr = array_unique($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [7] => 11
)
```

so now its time to count, just use `count`.

```
echo count($arr);// 2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `explode` the `string` on `,`
2. `array_filter` without callback, to remove empty matches (first comma)
3. `array_unique` to remove dup values
4. `count` to return the size of `array_unique`

---

```
$string = ",10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11";
echo count(array_unique(array_filter(explode(",", $string))));
```

Comment: Care to comment the DV ?

Comment: He doesn't. I've downvoted this homework assignment question and upvoted your answer. The most simple and effective here. - I'd personally used array_map(intval,...) instead of array_filter(...).

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this :

```
$string = '10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12';

$numbers = explode(',',$string);
$counter = array();
foreach($numbers as $num) {
   $num = trim($num);
   if (!empty($num)) {
      if (!isset($counter[$num])) {
         $counter[$num]=1;
      } else {
         $counter[$num]++;
      }
   }
}

print_r($counter);
```

Hope this help!